# Evaluate this product $n \times \frac{n-1}{2} \times \dots \times \frac{n-(2^k-1)}{2^k}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, summation, products

For $k = \lfloor \log_{2}(n+1) \rfloor - 1$ evaluate
$n \times \frac{n-1}{2} \times\frac{n-3}{4} \times \frac{n-7}{8}  \times \dots \times \frac{n-(2^{k}-1)}{2^k}$

So the product goes up to $k$ and I want to sub in $k = \lfloor \log_{2}(n+1) \rfloor - 1$ to evaluate:
$n \times \frac{n-1}{2} \times \dots \times \frac{n-(2^{( \lfloor \log_{2}(n+1) \rfloor -1)}-1}{2^{ \lfloor \log_{2}(n+1) \rfloor -1 } }$

To make computations less disgusting, I think it would be okay to assume that n is such that log(n+1)-1 is an integer.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Surely it is **crucial** to worry about ceiling and floor functions. You have a discrete product, how can we even tell what the factors are if you aren't indicating this clearly? Are the numerators, and the exponents in the denominators, supposed to be integral? Are they supposed to be complementary (summing to $n$)? This is extremely unclear. You should make the statement more concise or risk having the question removed.

Comment: Is that better? I didn't want it to be unclear, I merely meant "assume n is such that log(n+1) - 1 is an integer"

Comment: This still doesn't make sense. There appear to be $2i$ factors if you count numerators ($0,1,\ldots,2i-1$), but $i+1$ factorsif you count exponents in the denominators ($0,1,\ldots,i$). How many factors are there, and what is the formula for the generic $k$th factor???

Comment: i+1 factors. Apologies. Is this clearer?

Comment: I guess you mean $\frac{n-5}{8}$. And I see the first factor is an oddball that doesn't fit the pattern, since it would be $\frac{n+1}{2^0}$ -- that's intentional?

Comment: oh boy, so many errors. Finally I think I got it right. Apologies once again...

Comment: Please, don't use $\displaystyle{\Huge{\rm i}}$. It can be confused with $\displaystyle{\large\sqrt{-1}}$.

Comment: everything ok now? does anybody have some ideas? I'm totally stumped by this...